# Is it possible to conditionally show an XML include based on a classes method response?

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I'm wondering if it's possible to use DataBinding to do conditionally show a layout based on a methods boolean response. Here's what I'm trying to do

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="View"
            type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="App"
            type="com.app.JTApp"/>
    </data>

    <include layout="@layout/view_checkout_total_cardview"
             android:visibility="@{App.isLandscape() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />

</layout>
```

JTApp class:

```java
public class JTApp {

    public boolean isLandscape() {
        Timber.d("putty-- isLandscape: --------------------------");
        return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape);
    }

    …
}
```

Currently this doesn't work. Am I missing something or is this not possible? I'm coming from the web where this is possible with frameworks like Angular.

Comment: You can define two different layouts for portrait and landscape. I'm not sure this is the best use case for data binding

Comment: That's what I am doing until/unless I find a solution that doesn't require creating extra files.

Comment: I don't notice anything wrong with your code, are you getting any errors? Is `isLandscape()` getting called? Are you binding the `View` and the `JTApp` in your `Activity` correctly?

Comment: isLandscape is not getting called and I tried importing vs setting variable based on your answer yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using a conditional statement within XML is possible. I am not too familiar with data binding library, but a similar functionality is used in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#layout_details):

> Zero or more import elements may be used inside the data element.
>   These allow easy reference to classes inside your layout file, just
>   like in Java.
>
> ```
> <data>
>     <import type="android.view.View"/>
> </data>
> ```
>
> Now, View may be used within your binding expression:
>
> ```
> <TextView
>    android:text="@{user.lastName}"
>    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>    android:visibility="@{user.isAdult ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
> ```

I believe the only issue with your code is that you are using the `View` as a `variable` instead of as an `import` in your `<data>` element.

Comment: These reference variables but say nothing about using methods to check. I know I can automatically add an *isLandscape* variable to the app but that seems like overkill for my use case watching on config.

Comment: @MariusMiliunas Do you need to watch for configuration changes? Why not just let the `Activity` get recreated, then the data should be re-bound and check `isLandscape()` again, no? I haven't tested it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MariusMiliunas Ah, I do see what you are saying about the method check though. Missed that at first. *If* you cannot use a method, why not just bind a `Boolean` value instead of the `JTApp` class? Then just use `binding.setBoolean(JTApp.isLandscape())`.

Comment: I cannot make JTApp a binding because it's the root app instance and it will break many other things. Additionally I cannot use DataBinding on this view using the current Activity because our app was built on deeply inherited parent Activities that set the content view deep below. It was not built with DB in mind so here I was trying to see if it's possible to reference random packages that have the functionality I need that aren't built with DataBinding in mind either.

Comment: @MariusMiliunas If you are not using data binding with the current `Activity`, what are you using it with? Also, I don't see how using a method from your `Application` class will break other things. If `isLandscape()` is already a method, why can't you use it in other cases?

Comment: I was trying to use Data Binding purely for this one feature of NOT showing a layout on landscape since binding to my Activity breaks because the previously stated reason.

Comment: @MariusMiliunas The issue then, is that you cannot expect data to be available to a data bound layout if you do not actually bind any data; which makes your question seem a bit misleading. In any case, this means you cannot use a `<variable>` element within your layout if you are not actually binding any data. Though you *should* still be able to use an `<import>` tag. If you can make a `static` method that returns the orientation of the device, this could work, but I am not so sure that is possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way easier with resource-modifiers:

- have one layout in layout-land that does not contain the cardview
- have another layout in layout that does contain the cardview

so you will get this effect and in landscape it is not even inflated and then set invisible

Comment: While I agree this is a simpler method of achieving the same result, I don't think it answers the question. The question asks if it is *possible*, not if it is the best way. This was also covered in the comment by @cricket_007.

Comment: Agree - but I do not think it is better to show the right way for his problem than the right answer to his question ( which would be the wrong way )

Comment: No offense but you do not know the context of my situation.

Comment: Yes I only know the context you gave with your question